# Quick sort in C++. Almost correct but the outcome shifted

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I made a quicksort in C++ but it doesn't work well. For example, if I have an array of {5, 3, 4, 6, 7}, the outcome will be {0, 3, 4, 5, 6}. I can't find the reason since I used the same method in Pascal before and that worked perfectly.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void qsort(int (&ary)[10000], int l, int r){
    int i = l, j = r, mid = ary[(l + r) / 2];
    while (i <= j){
        while (ary[i] < mid) i ++;
        while (ary[j] > mid) j --;
        if (i <= j){
            int temp = ary[i];
            ary[i] = ary[j];
            ary[j] = temp;
            i ++; j --;
        }
    }
    if (i < r) qsort(ary, i, r);
    if (l < j) qsort(ary, l, j);
}

int main(){
    int n;
    int a[10000];
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++){
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    qsort(a, 0, n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++){
        cout << a[i] << ' ';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your algorithm, one line at a time, and observe the values of the array and all the variables used here, as they change, what observations did you make? Free clue: run your debugger and input an array with only one value, and feed it to your quicksort. Watch in amazement, as you step through your code, one line at a time, as your debugger shows you how your code pulls a rabbit out of a hat, and imagines that your array has mysteriously grown a second value! Learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I just learnt the debugger and I found out the problem. I should call qsort(a, 0, n - 1) instead of qsort(1, 0, n).

Comment: Run your algorithm with pen and paper by hand. Your example is so small that this should be no problem at all.

Answer (score -1):

line 27: should be
`qsort(a, 0, n-1);`

Comment: Add an explanation and the answer might become useful.